# How can I benchmark Linux PC

Tags: linux, benchmarking

I get a simple benchmark score from *Windows Experience Index*. Its Windows based. Is there anything similar in *Linux*?

It should be able to benchmark on

1. Memory
2. Disk
3. Graphics
4. Network
5. ... Something else?

And obviously it should be **free** or **open source**. Or at least the benchmarks I am seeking must be available on trial version.

Comment: Not [BogoMIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BogoMips)!

Comment: I'm disappointed this question is closed.  I use sysbench in Linux for this all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hardinfo](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2007/11/15/benchmark-your-linux-system-with-hardinfo/)

> HardInfo is a system profiler and benchmark for Linux systems. It can gather information about your computer and operating system, perform a varitety of benchmarks, and export the data to HTML.

[Heaven](http://unigine.com/products/heaven/)

> It is the first DirectX 11 benchmark in the world, the original version was released at the moment of Microsoft Windows 7 launch in October, 2009.
>   Operating system:
>   -  MS Windows XP
>   - MS Windows Vista
>   - MS Windows 7
>   - **GNU/Linux**

But see [ZDNet](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/hardware/is-vistas-windows-experience-index-fatally-flawed/37)

Comment: +1 HardInfo is a very decent tool, Shortcut link is: apt://hardinfo

Answer (score 1):

The Phoronix Test Suite : http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/

Comment: Whats so special about this suite? what will it test?

Comment: Read the web page, it lists the features and why you would want to use it. It's clearly explained.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.